# What would it take for aircraft to fully replace naval vessels?

Tags: warfare, technological-development

Assuming technology within the next century or so, what would it take for aircraft to fully replace naval vessels such that a navy and air force could almost merge?

While surface vessels and carriers seem like they could potentially fall to higher endurance aircraft and possibly something more exotic like airborne carriers or drone swarms, the harder problem seems to be submarines. I'm thinking would probably have to be something that could detect them fairly easily such that they are no longer able to remain undetected.

Comment: A ship will float in water without any outside intervention.   Aircraft must be kept aloft; lighter than air ones by artificial combinations of gas.  Nothing foreseeable will remove that advantage.

Comment: The heavy carrying-capacity of ships is unrivaled on land, in the air, or anywhere else.  Additionally, unlike air vehicles, they can be heavily armored.  The only way they could be "replaced" by air vehicles is if the sea was never tenable in the first place (i.e., Cloverfield-like monsters, etc.).

Comment: You said something about submarines being the problem, but, it is possible to [hunt submarines from the air](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-submarine_warfare#Platforms). (Example: check out [this piece of technology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aerial_torpedo) that exists since 100 years ago.. or more....)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

A miracle.

Let's suppose you want to make a show of force against some rival, or in support of an ally. What's more impressive, a carrier task force showing up, or some radar contacts? Who can sit there longer due to greater endurance? Say there's a natural disaster and you want to provide assistance that could end up being several months in duration. Who do you want to be there, a naval task force or some aircraft hanging around overhead?

You're making the same argument that was made in the late 1940s when some generals in their brand-new USAF uniforms, along with several politicians, stated that the need for a navy was a thing of the past. With the new long-range aircraft (and even longer-ranged ones on the way, like the B-52), and new weapons systems, including nukes, there was nothing the navy could do that the air force couldn't faster, cheaper, and with fewer men and equipment.

Seventy-five years later, how's that worked out?

There is, coincidentally, a video put out by the Templin Institute regarding thoughts on planetary invasions recently that is applicable because of the analogy between being able to bombard from orbit versus being able to put feet on the ground that specifically uses the "If we have an air force, why bother with a navy?" analogy:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XgN5yq362_s

The main point to take away: a naval presence gives you a lot more strategic and tactical flexibility and ability to choose the exact level of engagement you want to have. So barring something akin to antigravity tech or some kind of absurdly compact yet powerful energy source that allows something like a SHIELD helicarrier (ie, the aforementioned miracle), an air force cannot replace a navy any more than they can replace an army.

Comment: Maybe the planes could bring inflatable boats and blow them up once they get there.  Big impressive ones.

Comment: @Willk Keith's argument still holds, since we had [inflatable tanks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dummy_tank) in the 1940s, and the Air Force still didn't replace the Army.

Comment: "A miracle" So... a stash of unobtanium under a tree inhabited by blue sapiens?

Answer (score 17):

[**Wars Are Not Fought On Battlefields**](https://worldbeyondwar.org/wars-fought-battlefields/)

The glory-laden visual that a war is won by individual soldiers, armies, or dogfights is nothing more than a "sugar-high" designed to keep the support infrastructure motivated.

If the Navy ceases to exist then how do you properly protect your cargo ships transporting the necessities to keep your fighter planes in the sky?

Good luck getting this guy airborne:

[image]

Comment: You spelled "ceases" as "cases" BTW.

Comment: To put it in another way: (1) Ships, even small ships (like frigates) are **much bigger** than the biggest airplanes like the Antonov An-225. (2) The oceans are really damned huge.

Comment: The case could be made that in a sufficiently advanced civilization, long range weaponry is enough to protect civilian ships, without any need for the military to have ships of their own.

Comment: @Toddleson That's great and all except that an enemy vessel doesn't exactly have "enemy" plastered on the hull for you to simply pew-pew at will.

Comment: If these ships are routinely being sunk by enemy aircraft, it doesn't particularly matter how useful they are, they may simply not be an option.

Comment: @user37344 Is it currently a problem? Keep the aircrafts in the sky and boats/submarines in the sea.

Answer (score 16):

## Killing everything in the sea

Have a nanite experiment designed to fix global warming fill the sea with repliacting robots that consume metal and anything within them.

Anything that floats in the water will be consumed, and efforts to insert counter agents haven't succeeded. As such, all travel needs to be by air.

Comment: This would really become apocalyptic, when sea level rise would proceed. In that case, rivers would get easily infected by these little robots as well. btw automatic procreation of these robots would soon exhaust certain resources needed for batteries and electronics.. manganese, gold, silver.. they'll vanish.

Comment: @Goodies The nanobots are just collecting all those metals, so we can replace strip mining by dragging a big magnet through the ocean.

Comment: The nanites are programmed to stay in the sea, and they seem to be doing so in this answer. And yeah, mining the sea is possible, if dangerous.

Answer (score 5):

**I figure you'd need a few things:**

Fast aircraft. Very fast. Say contingency-response time down to eyes-on-target in less than an hour. That's about MACH 27 (compare [Sprint missile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sprint_(missile))). Globally, so including faff and round-trips say 30,000 miles (~50,000 Km) trip-length.

*Which would require:*

Huge amounts of energy to propel an object through the atmosphere, propellers won't do, jets have their limits too. Rockets need propellant, heavy. How about an [EmDrive](http://www.emdrive.com/IAC20212Gpaper.pdf) powered by fusion. (I'm not convinced the whole EmDrive thing's not an elaborate joke, but what do I know).

Also, very rugged ablative shielding, typically a blunt-ended affair, to direct the hot plasma created at high speeds away from the body of the craft. (Possibly also some elaborate mechanics at the front so it can be replaced in-flight).

**Or:**

The ability to create point-to-point wormholes between start and destination, you could still then have jets or even propeller-aircraft if you wished and refuelling would be a hop and jump, then out to fight again.

.............................................

Now, as to the submarine issue, competition between detection and concealment would make things unpredictable, as evolution is - expect it to come up with new/unexpected and sometimes unlikely solutions (as well as the run-of-the-mill convergent ones like shoals of swarming drones that look and sound like fish). Should be the topic of another question.

Comment: Problem with response-times like that is that what you describe sounds pretty much like a cruise missile.. I imagine that post-coldwar nerves will be wildly frayed by that kind of radar-contact showing up on the horizon.

Answer (score 5):

**Portable fusion reactors**

The main disadvantage of trying to replace surface craft with aircraft is the much lower loiter time. What if that wasn't a problem?

There were brief attempts at designing and building [fission-powered planes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear-powered_aircraft). If you could build a unit with the equivalent power to weight output of a jet engine that ran for weeks without refuelling, and without emitting too much radiation for nearby electronics or humans, you'd be able to have flocks of permanently loitering drones surveilling the sea. Behind them you'd have the airborne equivalent of the missile cruiser, a large (B52-size) craft carrying a selection of air-to-air and air-to-ground missiles which could then engage threats over the horizon, guided by the scout drones and satellites.

Comment: On the other hand, this seems like the Energy vs Kinetic weapon or Mech vs Tank argument in another guise. If you have the power-to-weight to make perpetual-planes possible, then the same technology could make a wet-navy substantially more capable too. Nuclear Power has done some fantastic things for the navy already, even more compact/low-maintenance nuclear reactors would effectively remove the fuel requirements for naval patrols because all ships could have them rather than just the big ones.

Comment: @Ruadhan: I think propulsion for ships is relatively easy already and wouldn’t benefit from huge breakthroughs in power generation.

Comment: @Michael no, it's a reasonable point that fusion reactors would let you build overpowered surface ships; if power and fuel is no consequence, why not have a catamaran aircraft carrier that could do sixty or seventy knots?

Comment: @pjc50: That would be an improvement, but not a huge one. Aircraft which can stay in the air for days without refueling or fly around the globe would be a huge improvement.

Comment: @Michael, not really because they're still limited in what they can actually do except loiter around longer or go longer distances. If you had a fighter that could stay up there for days, it still only has a handful of missiles and only so many rounds for any cannon. Once it's shot its wad, it doesn't matter if it can hang around for another 72 hours.

Comment: While this goes a good way towards solving the issue, planes still need to land for maintenance.

Comment: Aside from fuel costs, a fighter that can loiter for days is still limited by its pilot. They've got to be able to eat, sleep, shower, defecate... Either your nuclear powered superfighter is remote-operated, or it's big enough for a crew of two or three to operate it in shifts. In which case you're looking at something much bigger and more in the vein of a nuclear powered gunship.

Answer (score 2):

Well.. with "next century", let's say in a 100 years, a lot can happen.

For aircraft, I'm more optimistic than Keith's answer. It will develop further.

**Combination is the key (now)**

Of course, the *combination* works best: ships have a huge range and provide a base to operate from. Aircraft carriers protected by ships provide the aircraft with a takeoff and landing place, aircraft will penetrate enemy territory.

But when aircraft would develop further, e.g. energy use would be limited, their range could become much wider, eliminating the need for carrier ships.

**Tactical advantages**

There are a few tactical advantages of aircraft.. Aircraft is much faster than ship. An aircraft can sneak in and *drop bombs*, missiles launched from ships and submarines are much longer visible, they could be intercepted.

Penetration advantage: aircraft can be deployed to reach visible targets inland, and cloaked using stealth radar deflection, which would become very expensive for larger scale objects like ships.

In 100 years, aircraft could use *beam weapons* to target anything anywhere, ships have a very limited reach for beam weapons (near aircraft, other ships, the coast)

**Scale advantages**

A large ship can cost billions. In next 100 years, unmanned military aircraft and drone swarms will evolve, endangering any large scale military object, with a relatively low cost operation.

Answer (score 2):

1. All airplanes need to become seaplanes without losing their tactical abilities;
2. At least cargo airplanes need to increase their payload capacity tenfold (so it can go beyond 1000 tons), without significant increase in operating costs.

Navy vessels have advantage of staying deployed for long period of time at a relatively low cost. All existing aircraft have very limited flight time, and refueling them in the air is logistically very difficult. Seaplane can land and effectively become a boat, but today it's a very poor boat and a very poor plane.

Navy vessels can carry a lot of cargo and personnel. Today, there is no way to deploy significant ground force to another continent without using a boat.

Comment: Counterpoint: The current trend in military action is for smaller and more capable forces, rather than bulk numbers and heavy ground-vehicles. The old ways were intended for fighting the Soviets and those tactics are in the process of being phased out. I could well imagine that a near-future military might well be fully air-liftable.

Comment: You’re missing point 1b: Weather needs to change such that seaplanes are actually viable. There’s a reason that nobody sane uses them anymore except in highly specific circumstances.

Comment: @Ruadhan we can do a lot more using precision strikes, but if we need to occupy territory, there is no foreseeable replacement for "boots on the ground".

Comment: @Ruadhan, until they run up against an enemy who does things "the old way" and then suddenly they need the heavy equipment.

Comment: @Alexander The convenient thing about decent air-lift capability is that you absolutely can move lots of people around quite quickly. So Boots-on-the-ground is still very viable. The real limiting factor is the 60 - 70 ton heavy battle tanks that have very few ways to get where they're needed except by sea. The C-17 Globemaster is one of the very few aircraft capable of actually transporting one of those, and it only takes one at a time. The C-5 Galaxy can take two at a time and it's one of the largest aircraft in the world.. Without sea-transportation, the US military is badly musclebound.

Comment: @Ruadhan when we are moving a marine battalion, for example, we are not moving just 1000 people weighting 70-80 kg each. We are moving a LOT of equipment and supplies - without even touching tanks yet. That's why US today can not wage even a small-scale conventional war without marine transports.

Answer (score 2):

**War as we know it must change dramatically**

Every hour you spend fighting requires, depending on your platform, 2-10 times more time to be spent repairing or maintaining the vehicles. While fighting is important, every fighting force requires logistics, and needs to be resupplied in the field. Fighter jets are terrible at moving ordinance, it is more efficient to use cargo craft or even better, ships. The reason navies still exist is boats are efficient at carrying things long distances for low cost. An aircraft carrier is refueling rearm and repair station. Even extremely fast aircraft can’t beat a slower aircraft that needs to only go to the carrier instead of going back to a home base. The reduced cost of moving ordinance is also a big benefit.

**high efficiency, extreme speed engines**

If the cost of moving ordinance across seas is lower by air, planes can deliver comparable ordinance, and the speed of resupply is roughly the same as carrier operations, then airplanes will be better. If any of that doesn’t happen, it won’t happen.

Answer (score 1):

Ships have a tremendous advantage over aircraft: They are so cheap transporting things (airplanes, ordnance, missiles) to the deployment area that it is not just possible but even realistically done that you keep entire battle fleets permanently deployed, without driving your national economy into bankruptcy.

So for naval vessels to become useless, you have to make them useless in a conflict.
E.g. submarines are so effective in sinking ships that a carrier group is demoted from "threat" to "easy target". (Submarine staff tends to boast that they can sink any carrier without a problem, but I guess the high-level staff disagrees, else we wouldn't have carrier groups anymore.)
There was the idea of filling the sea with nanites, but that's pretty outlandish. Fleets of automatic killer submarines would work just as well. Essentially mines, but mines with a propulsion, and anything that moves and does not have the right challenge response gets attacked - those killer submarines have have to be cheap enough to be produced en masse.

Note that such a development would also kill international trade, and the basis for much of today's economy.
Land transport is just SO much more expensive than sea transport.
Also, land owners can block routes with relative ease, so you get a geopolitical situation where all land bridges (Egypt, Turkey, Panama) become hotly contested military hotspots. Islands (Taiwan, Japan etc.) would become horribly backwater.
UNLESS civilian transponders are allowed by all killer subs of all nations. This might actually work, but it would give each killer sub owning nation the ability to threaten that they kill international trade, so even with this scenario you'd have massive changes to geopolitics.

Answer (score 1):

**Advancement and spread in Suborbital Flight and Suborbital Space/Aerostations, combined with some catastrophic event that deters naval travel or terrestrial habitats.**

"Replace" is a very strong word. Naval vessels and Aircraft might broadly overlap in things they can do, they are extremely different things, used in entirely different areas. One does not make the other obsolete. One cannot be replaced without specific deterrant from using it.

Think about how CD-Roms, Fax Machines, heck, Pencil and Paper are still used today. The printing press didn't replace the pencil. The typewriter didn't replace the pencil. Computers didn't fully replace the pencil. Even iPads didn't fully replace the pencil.

Let's get back to Naval vessels. Did discovery of seafaring make caravans obsolete? No, not really, it offered an alternative route to the destination be it for trade or travel. Sea routes sometimes give a better direct path to the destination than by land, sometimes it doesn't, but sailing around a peninsula might help avoid bandits, enemy borders, or complex city infrastrucure in a developed world.

Okay, so that's just logistics. What about militarily? Sea and Air gives very different attack vectors. I guarantee even in a hypothetical Air/space-dominated future naval weapon platforms will still be used if only to get great coverage outside of civilian areas to launch nukes to destroy those aircraft. There's so much real estate in the open seas, why the heck wouldn't you use it?

So in order for the scenario to work, there must be some catastrophic event to make the seas unviable. Doomsday level event. Endless torrents, a new ice age, sea becomes toxic, etc. or WW3 happened and sea-level atmosphere is completely irradiated, forcing mankind to live in the skies.

As for technological requirements, we're actually pretty close if not there already. Suborbital flight is the future of commercial flights as it is much faster means of air travel and less costly in fuel etc. It should be feasible to construct a suborbital airport/station that seemingly hovers in the sky, though the bulk of the infrastructure might still be on the orbital stations.

Another way to make suborbital stations or perpetually airborne atmospheric stations/aircraft plausible would be greatly thickening the atmosphere. It is theorized that on Venus, it makes more sense to build aerostat habitats than to deal with the scorching, hazardous surface. If soem catastrophic event or asteroid collision causes a drastic change in the Earth's atmosphere to make it become similar to Venus, that could be a good reason for aircraft to fully replace naval vessels, but that's also a case of combination of ease of floating on the atmosphere and oceans having simply ceased to exist.

Answer (score 0):

Traditional naval combat was basically replaced by arial combat during WW2. In those days (and maybe even today, I'm no expert) the limited flight range of planes made it necessary to have aircraft carriers for delivering air power, but the various naval guns, smaller ships like destroyers, and submarines were all ultimately there to either protect carriers from planes or, in the submarine case, to sink an enemy carrier and therefore also destroy their arial fleet. If you just give your planes a very long flight range then you circumvent the need for the fleet entirely. Since this is a Sci-Fi setting, you could even give the planes a more-or-less indefinite flight range by having them be solar powered or wirelessly recharged from ground based power plants.

Also, stealth planes are a thing. So are, in principle, are satellites with weapons attached. Those could be options if you want to have an "attack from out of nowhere" type capability.

Edit: As far as I can tell, the OP is looking to give up combat vessels. They could still keep cargo vessels. Who's going to protect those cargo vessels? Well, the arial fleet can do that. That said, even if the OP does want to give up cargo vessels as well, I don't think that'd be hard to justify. As a general rule, they are fairly easy targets and it may well be worth taking the supply chain hit to just supply troops by air-lift. It's not like that's never been done before and, again, if flight-range isn't an issue then I don't see any reason this couldn't become the new standard.

Further Edit: It seems like some answers are basically saying that this can't be done because ships are needed to move materials. If naval power can't keep up with air power, then cargo and combat ships alike will be sitting ducks to air-power, especially if, again, the aircraft can stalk the seas without concern for flight distance. If the flight-range problem is solved and Navies can't defend against air attacks then it doesn't matter how much you "need" your cargo ships, they aren't an option. In short, it doesn't matter whether the logistics side of thing is worse in an air-only world.

Comment: As noted above, this means that you are limited to exactly one type of response: blow stuff up. Want to enforce a blockade? You have to blow ships up. Inspect ships you think are circumventing a weapons embargo? Well, you really can only blow them up. Determine if that's a shipload of refugees are some terrorists in disguise? Well, after you blow them up, since that's the only thing you can do, it won't matter.

Comment: Submarines in WW2 were primarily dedicated to destroying enemy cargo ships, they lacked the speed to hunt down combatant vessels and as per @MonkeyZeus answer the logistics war is the one that matters in the long run.

Comment: @KeithMorrison I guess you can literally "block" when blockading with a ship, but I think the threat is of blowing up ships in each case is the main threat. You can also airdrop troops to do things like inspect a ship. I assume helicopters are still a thing in this world.

Comment: @KerrAvon2055 Logistics can be done by air. It may cost more, but so does maintaining a Navy. More importantly, if the cargo and combat ships both end up just being sitting ducks to aircraft it doesn't matter how much the troops need the cargo, they won't be getting it and their country will need to make due with air lifts.

Comment: @user37344, helicopters flying out of where? Boy, it would be real convenient to have some kind of vessel the helicopters could be based off of so you could place them where they needed to be.

Comment: @KeithMorrison (1) The OP wants to know under what circumstances you could have an airforce replace a navy. I responded to that question. If you don't like that idea, this may not be the question for you.

Comment: @KeithMorrison (2) I could just as well say "ships flying out of nowhere?" You are aware that ships also have to move to get to where they are needed too, yes? I made very clear twice than my principle condition is unlimited or practically unlimited flight range. Under such a condition, helicopters would be (a) able to move much faster on their own power than they could on a ship and (b) they could be much more spread out since they aren't tied to a large ship meant to hold many. So, relatively speaking, the helicopters would appear to come from nowhere.

Comment: @KeithMorrison (3) You could well have tried a "planes flying from nowhere" type response in your first comment, but I assume at that point you still remembered the unlimited flight range condition. This logic is quite simple. The most important ships around today are carriers. If flight length is unlimited, there's much less use for a carrier. Most important combat operations are carried out by planes and helicopters anyway.

Answer (score -4):

#### Simple

Just wait for *Man-Made Global Warming <sup>(TM)</sup>* to do its work! They've been saying the oceans will dry up in the next five years for at least the last thirty years. One of these days, all that stock in Northop Grummond will make you a mint!

[image]

It's not due to global warming, but there is one sea on Earth that isn't really a sea anymore. :(

[image]

Comment: Who are those "they"?  No, the oceans won't dry up in the foreseeable future, not even in a million years. And if the temperature continues to rise, the ocean level will tend to rise a little, rather than drop, due to ice at the poles melting.